# How do I create a Facebook app to be used by our clients to display information to their customers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I struggled to sum this up in a title, so apologies if it is a little misleading. I'll talk specifics.

We currently have a web based application that a large number of clients, and within that application each client can have multiple forms hosted that they use to collect data from their customers.

We would like to be able to **facilitate our clients to add these forms to their Facebook fan pages as tabs so that their customers can fill them in directly on Facebook**. The simpler this process is for our clients the better. The end user should not be aware that the form is a separate application and should not have to allow access.

I envisage a Facebook app that allows the client to authenticate with their login, before being presented with a list of their available forms. Once selected this form would then be stored against the fan page so that customers of their client would see the desired form.

As I am a complete novice to development on Facebook, I was interested to know whether this is the best approach and if so a few starter points if possible. I understand that the application will be hosted by ourselves externally, I have created basic apps to get a feel for the setup on Facebook and had a play with the C# SDK and got authentication working.

1) Is this possible?

2) How do I differentiate between the client/admin and the customer/user to present the authentication and editing or just the form?

3) I'm making the assumption that we would have to store the identifier of the chosen form locally against a page ID. Does this sound correct?

Any help appreciated, generally to just to lead me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It's possible the way you pointed out.

2) You now if it's an admin or not, by parsing and handling the SignedRequest Facebook posted to your page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

This signed_request contains data like: user_is_fan?, user_is_admin?, page_id

3) Correct, see signed request above, which contains a page_id.

**edit**:

Good tool to parse given signed_requests:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo/?signed_request= (just add your signed_request here)

Comment: The exact property I am looking for is "SignedRequest.Data.page.admin" using the C# SDK. Thanks a lot.